# not able to connect view controoller to appdelegate in main window nib

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

i have added an view controler to interface builder and trying to add connection but is not allowing to connect, buti have created ib outlet for that and is visible in IB...

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to give controller name in IB ui view controller